# Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Undefined array key "content_css"

Tags: magento2, installation, custom-theme, magentomodule, third-party-plugin

I successfully installed the Martfury Marketplace Magento Theme along with the Magefan Blog Module. My intention was to edit the homepage after activating the theme. However, upon pressing the edit button, I encountered an error code.
[image]

Wysiwyg.php on line 114,
[image]

Please anyone can help me to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle the Undefined array key of content_css on line no 114 using the below code.

```
$mainCss = $result->getData('tinymce')['content_css'];
```

**Change above line code to below line of code.**

```
$mainCss = isset($result->getData('tinymce')['content_css']) ? $result->getData('tinymce')['content_css']: '';
```

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check now.

Comment: Thank you sir it works !

Comment: Hi, I happy to hear that. Please accept my answer by providing upvote. So, It will help other community user.